# Replace document with the iframe's document

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, cross-domain

I have a webpage that displays an iframe containing a random website. After 10 seconds I want the website within the iframe to replace the "parent" website.

Let's say my website www.aaa.com has an iframe containing the website www.bbb.com. After 10 seconds I want the browser to replace the currently open www.aaa.com with www.bbb.com without reloading the page so the user doesn't lose their state. Basically replacing the document and updating the URL bar accordingly.

I can't just get the URL of the iframe and change location as the user could for instance be watching a video and it would start again from the beginning because of the page reload.

I've been searching for this for a few hours and there is absolutely nothing that I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `window.location = "//www.bbb.com"` but it will just fetch that webpage as usual.

You can set an url in the browser using `window.history.replaceState(null, "test", "www.aaa.com/mypage?foo=bar")` but it will fail crossdomain (it will even fail using a subdomain on your site).

And you cannot get the contents of a cross-domain iframe.

These are all related to cross-origin security. There may be exceptions, such as when you have elevated permissions (browser plugin). Some functionality *may* be available using CORS and what not, but you need cooperation from the owner of the other domain.

In short, the closest to what you want is probably to set the iframe to the full width/height of the window.

Comment: The browser plugin might be an option. My users all have my extension to receive alerts so maybe I can use it for that. I'll look into it. Thank you for your thoughts.